# Find Rows Where There Are At Least N Consecutive Values

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I'm having trouble identifying rows where 10 or more nulls exist, plus the rows before and after so I can see what the values were. I've gotten pretty far efficiently identifying the nulls, but my problem is isolating blocks of 10 or more null values, plus the rows before and after, and placing those into a new dataframe.

Here is a sample of the data I am working with:

```
new_df = 
engine_serial_number    occurrence_date_time                spn                                     rn      isSpnValue  spn_grp spn_count   spn_start   soc_end
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:20.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1668    0           1374    0           1           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:20.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1669    1           1374    1           2           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:21.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1670    1           1374    2           0           1
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:21.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1671    0           1375    0           1           2
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:22.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1672    1           1375    1           0           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:22.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1673    0           1376    0           1           1
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:23.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1674    1           1376    1           0           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:23.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1675    0           1377    0           0           1
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:24.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1676    0           1378    0           1           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:24.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1677    1           1378    1           2           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:25.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1678    1           1378    2           0           1
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:25.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1679    0           1379    0           0           2
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:26.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1680    0           1380    0           1           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:26.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1681    1           1380    1           2           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:27.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1682    1           1380    2           0           1
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:27.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1683    0           1381    0           0           2
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:28.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1684    0           1382    0           1           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:28.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1685    1           1382    1           2           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:29.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1686    1           1382    2           0           1
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:29.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1687    0           1383    0           0           2
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:30.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1688    0           1384    0           1           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:46.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1689    1           1384    1           2           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:47.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1690    1           1384    2           3           1
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:48.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1691    1           1384    3           4           2
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:49.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1692    1           1384    4           5           3
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:50.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1693    1           1384    5           6           4
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:51.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1694    1           1384    6           7           5
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:52.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1695    1           1384    7           8           6
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:53.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1696    1           1384    8           9           7
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:54.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1697    1           1384    9           10          8
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:55.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1698    1           1384    10          11          9
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:56.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1699    1           1384    11          0           10
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:57.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1700    0           1385    0           0           11
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:58.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1701    0           1386    0           1           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:59.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1702    1           1386    1           2           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:00.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1703    1           1386    2           0           1
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:01.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1704    0           1387    0           1           2
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:02.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1705    1           1387    1           0           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:03.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1706    0           1388    0           1           1
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:04.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1707    1           1388    1           0           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:05.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1708    0           1389    0           0           1
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:06.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1709    0           1390    0           1           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:07.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1710    1           1390    1           2           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:08.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1711    1           1390    2           3           1
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:09.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1712    1           1390    3           4           2
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:10.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1713    1           1390    4           5           3
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:11.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1714    1           1390    5           6           4
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:12.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1715    1           1390    6           7           5
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:13.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1716    1           1390    7           8           6
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:14.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1717    1           1390    8           9           7
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:15.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1718    1           1390    9           10          8
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:16.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1719    1           1390    10          11          9
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:17.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1720    1           1390    11          0           10
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:18.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1721    0           1391    0           0           11
```

"rn" is the row number. "isSpnValue" puts a 1 where spn is null, and a 0 where it is non-null. "spn_grp" increments in the presence of a non-null vale in the spn column. "spn_count" counts thre null vales in each group, and "spn_start" and "spn_end" are just lead and lag cokumns of "spn_count."

Here is the code I have written thus far to try and solve my problem:

```
counts_with_at_least_10 = new_df.where(((col("soc_start") >= 1) & (col("soc_end") >= 10)) | \
                                       ((col("tvd_start") >= 1) & (col("tvd_end") >= 10)) | \
                                       ((col("spn_start") >= 1) & (col("spn_end") >= 10)))
```

I was attempting to use the lead and lag columns to achieve my goal but it was also catching blocks of nulls that were less than 10 as well. I also tried counting by groups:

```
counts_with_at_least_10 = new_df.groupBy('spn_grp').count().where(col('count') > 9)
```

This is the result I am expecting:

```
engine_serial_number    occurrence_date_time                spn                                     rn      isSpnValue  spn_grp spn_count   spn_start   soc_end
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:30.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1688    0           1384    0           1           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:46.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1689    1           1384    1           2           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:47.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1690    1           1384    2           3           1
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:48.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1691    1           1384    3           4           2
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:49.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1692    1           1384    4           5           3
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:50.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1693    1           1384    5           6           4
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:51.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1694    1           1384    6           7           5
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:52.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1695    1           1384    7           8           6
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:53.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1696    1           1384    8           9           7
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:54.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1697    1           1384    9           10          8
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:55.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1698    1           1384    10          11          9
83500600                2023-09-25 09:51:56.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1699    1           1384    11          0           10
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:19.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1700    0           1385    0           0           11
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:06.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1709    0           1390    0           1           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:07.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1710    1           1390    1           2           0
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:08.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1711    1           1390    2           3           1
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:09.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1712    1           1390    3           4           2
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:10.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1713    1           1390    4           5           3
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:11.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1714    1           1390    5           6           4
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:12.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1715    1           1390    6           7           5
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:13.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1716    1           1390    7           8           6
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:14.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1717    1           1390    8           9           7
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:15.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1718    1           1390    9           10          8
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:16.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1719    1           1390    10          11          9
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:17.000 2023-09-25  null                                    1720    1           1390    11          0           10
83500600                2023-09-25 09:52:18.000 2023-09-25  [563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]  1721    0           1391    0           0           11
```

This shows the groups that I need, but it produces a dataframe of groups and their counts and it is missing the row after the nulls.

Would anyone be able to help me with this problem? It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

#### Step by Step Solution

Create window spec `W1` to partition the dataframe by engine number and order by date

```
W1 = Window.partitionBy('engine_serial_number').orderBy('occurrence_date_time')
```

Calculate the cumulative count of non null values over `W1` to identify groups of different consecutive rows having nulls

```
m1 = F.col('spn').isNotNull()
df1 = df.withColumn('null_grp', F.sum(m1.cast('long')).over(W1))

# df1.show()
# +--------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------+--------+
# |engine_serial_number|occurrence_date_time              |spn                                   |rn  |isSpnValue|spn_grp|spn_count|spn_start|soc_end|null_grp|
# +--------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------+--------+
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:20.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1668|0         |1374   |0        |1        |0      |1       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:20.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1669|1         |1374   |1        |2        |0      |1       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:21.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1670|1         |1374   |2        |0        |1      |2       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:21.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1671|0         |1375   |0        |1        |2      |2       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:22.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1672|1         |1375   |1        |0        |0      |3       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:22.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1673|0         |1376   |0        |1        |1      |3       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:23.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1674|1         |1376   |1        |0        |0      |4       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:23.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1675|0         |1377   |0        |0        |1      |4       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:24.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1676|0         |1378   |0        |1        |0      |5       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:24.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1677|1         |1378   |1        |2        |0      |5       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:25.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1678|1         |1378   |2        |0        |1      |6       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:25.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1679|0         |1379   |0        |0        |2      |6       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:26.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1680|0         |1380   |0        |1        |0      |7       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:26.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1681|1         |1380   |1        |2        |0      |7       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:27.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1682|1         |1380   |2        |0        |1      |8       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:27.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1683|0         |1381   |0        |0        |2      |8       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:28.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1684|0         |1382   |0        |1        |0      |9       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:28.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1685|1         |1382   |1        |2        |0      |9       |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:29.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1686|1         |1382   |2        |0        |1      |10      |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:29.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1687|0         |1383   |0        |0        |2      |10      |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:30.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1688|0         |1384   |0        |1        |0      |11      |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:46.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1689|1         |1384   |1        |2        |0      |11      |
# ...
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:17.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1720|1         |1390   |11       |0        |10     |17      |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:18.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1721|0         |1391   |0        |0        |11     |18      |
# +--------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------+--------+
```

Create window specification `W2` to partition the dataframe by engine number along with null group id

```
W2 = Window.partitionBy('engine_serial_number', 'null_grp')
```

Calculate the size of each null group per `W2`

```
df1 = df1.withColumn('null_grp_size', F.sum(F.lit(1)).over(W2))

# df1.show()
# +--------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
# |engine_serial_number|occurrence_date_time              |spn                                   |rn  |isSpnValue|spn_grp|spn_count|spn_start|soc_end|null_grp|null_grp_size|
# +--------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:20.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1668|0         |1374   |0        |1        |0      |1       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:20.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1669|1         |1374   |1        |2        |0      |1       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:21.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1670|1         |1374   |2        |0        |1      |2       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:21.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1671|0         |1375   |0        |1        |2      |2       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:22.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1672|1         |1375   |1        |0        |0      |3       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:22.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1673|0         |1376   |0        |1        |1      |3       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:23.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1674|1         |1376   |1        |0        |0      |4       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:23.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1675|0         |1377   |0        |0        |1      |4       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:24.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1676|0         |1378   |0        |1        |0      |5       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:24.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1677|1         |1378   |1        |2        |0      |5       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:25.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1678|1         |1378   |2        |0        |1      |6       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:25.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1679|0         |1379   |0        |0        |2      |6       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:26.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1680|0         |1380   |0        |1        |0      |7       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:26.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1681|1         |1380   |1        |2        |0      |7       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:27.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1682|1         |1380   |2        |0        |1      |8       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:27.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1683|0         |1381   |0        |0        |2      |8       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:28.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1684|0         |1382   |0        |1        |0      |9       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:28.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1685|1         |1382   |1        |2        |0      |9       |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:29.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1686|1         |1382   |2        |0        |1      |10      |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:29.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1687|0         |1383   |0        |0        |2      |10      |2            |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:30.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1688|0         |1384   |0        |1        |0      |11      |12           |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:46.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1689|1         |1384   |1        |2        |0      |11      |12           |
# ...
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:17.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1720|1         |1390   |11       |0        |10     |17      |12           |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:18.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1721|0         |1391   |0        |0        |11     |18      |1            |
# +--------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+
```

Create a boolean mask to flag the rows where the size is greater than or equal to the desired number. Notice here we are taking a logical or of the mask with lagged mask since we want to include boundary rows

```
m2 = F.col('null_grp_size') >= 9 # 10 - excluding first row
df1 = df1.withColumn('null_grp_mask', F.lag(m2).over(W1) | m2)

# df1.show()
# +--------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+
# |engine_serial_number|occurrence_date_time              |spn                                   |rn  |isSpnValue|spn_grp|spn_count|spn_start|soc_end|null_grp|null_grp_size|null_grp_mask|
# +--------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:20.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1668|0         |1374   |0        |1        |0      |1       |2            |null         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:20.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1669|1         |1374   |1        |2        |0      |1       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:21.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1670|1         |1374   |2        |0        |1      |2       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:21.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1671|0         |1375   |0        |1        |2      |2       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:22.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1672|1         |1375   |1        |0        |0      |3       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:22.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1673|0         |1376   |0        |1        |1      |3       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:23.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1674|1         |1376   |1        |0        |0      |4       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:23.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1675|0         |1377   |0        |0        |1      |4       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:24.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1676|0         |1378   |0        |1        |0      |5       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:24.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1677|1         |1378   |1        |2        |0      |5       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:25.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1678|1         |1378   |2        |0        |1      |6       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:25.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1679|0         |1379   |0        |0        |2      |6       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:26.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1680|0         |1380   |0        |1        |0      |7       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:26.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1681|1         |1380   |1        |2        |0      |7       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:27.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1682|1         |1380   |2        |0        |1      |8       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:27.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1683|0         |1381   |0        |0        |2      |8       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:28.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1684|0         |1382   |0        |1        |0      |9       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:28.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1685|1         |1382   |1        |2        |0      |9       |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:29.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1686|1         |1382   |2        |0        |1      |10      |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:29.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1687|0         |1383   |0        |0        |2      |10      |2            |false        |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:30.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1688|0         |1384   |0        |1        |0      |11      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:46.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1689|1         |1384   |1        |2        |0      |11      |12           |true         |
# ...
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:17.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1720|1         |1390   |11       |0        |10     |17      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:18.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1721|0         |1391   |0        |0        |11     |18      |1            |true         |
# +--------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```

Filter the rows where mask is True

```
df1 = df1.filter('null_grp_mask')

# df1.show()
# +--------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+
# |engine_serial_number|occurrence_date_time              |spn                                   |rn  |isSpnValue|spn_grp|spn_count|spn_start|soc_end|null_grp|null_grp_size|null_grp_mask|
# +--------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:30.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1688|0         |1384   |0        |1        |0      |11      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:46.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1689|1         |1384   |1        |2        |0      |11      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:47.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1690|1         |1384   |2        |3        |1      |11      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:48.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1691|1         |1384   |3        |4        |2      |11      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:49.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1692|1         |1384   |4        |5        |3      |11      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:50.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1693|1         |1384   |5        |6        |4      |11      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:51.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1694|1         |1384   |6        |7        |5      |11      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:52.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1695|1         |1384   |7        |8        |6      |11      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:53.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1696|1         |1384   |8        |9        |7      |11      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:54.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1697|1         |1384   |9        |10       |8      |11      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:55.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1698|1         |1384   |10       |11       |9      |11      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:56.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1699|1         |1384   |11       |0        |10     |11      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:51:57.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1700|0         |1385   |0        |0        |11     |12      |1            |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:06.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1709|0         |1390   |0        |1        |0      |17      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:07.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1710|1         |1390   |1        |2        |0      |17      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:08.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1711|1         |1390   |2        |3        |1      |17      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:09.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1712|1         |1390   |3        |4        |2      |17      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:10.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1713|1         |1390   |4        |5        |3      |17      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:11.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1714|1         |1390   |5        |6        |4      |17      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:12.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1715|1         |1390   |6        |7        |5      |17      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:13.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1716|1         |1390   |7        |8        |6      |17      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:14.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1717|1         |1390   |8        |9        |7      |17      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:15.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1718|1         |1390   |9        |10       |8      |17      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:16.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1719|1         |1390   |10       |11       |9      |17      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:17.000 2023-09-25|null                                  |1720|1         |1390   |11       |0        |10     |17      |12           |true         |
# |83500600            |2023-09-25 09:52:18.000 2023-09-25|[563,525,311,521271,521382,521383,639]|1721|0         |1391   |0        |0        |11     |18      |1            |true         |
# +--------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----+----------+-------+---------+---------+-------+--------+-------------+-------------+
```